# geom_dotplot spacing between dodged groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, dot-plot

I am created a dodged dotplot in R and would like to even the space between the categories within each group. All the time of day groups have four bars of dots in each, with the exception of the evening group. As a result, the dots in the evening group have greater spacing in between each other along the x axis. How can I even the spacing. If using `geom_bar` instead, I know I could use `preserve = 'single'` to achieve this, but this isn't possible with `geom_dotplot`.

[image: Here is my current plot]`

```
ggplot(joined_most_recent, aes(x = Time_of_day, fill = ease)) +
  geom_dotplot( binwidth = .5, method = "histodot", dotsize = .23, position = "dodge")+guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Ease of Recall"))+ scale_fill_manual(values=wes_palette("Darjeeling1"))
```

Here is my code ^